# Explain the math behind progressively reaching a target position

Tags: algorithm, math, game-physics

I'm trying to make an object position to reach to anther one. Instead of using the vector difference between the two directly,which that's according to the normalized difference vector to move forward. but i have seen people calculate it in a weird way.

Here is some pseudo-code. Let's assume that "A" wants to move to B.

```
// called every frame
function update()
{
    Vec3 diff = B.position - A.position;
    diff/=100;   
    A.position = A.position + diff;
}
```

Sure, the way to reach target position involves damping. Indeed, 
it needs to be iterated over and over again. Anyway, it finally gets to that target position. So what's math behind it? Do I need calculus to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two good answers, but they're not going into the mathematical theory behind the algorithm. The code actually describes a [linear first-order ordinary differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx).

Latex is not supported on SO, so I'll just write it as text. The ODE is described by:

> d**a**/dt = 1/100 * (-**a** + **b**)

I'm using bold notation, as `a` and `b` can be vectors. If you follow the link above, you can see the equation can be rewritten as

> da/dt + p(t)*a = g(t)

Where `p(t) = 1/100` and `g(t) = 1/100 * b`. From this follows (link again) `mu(t)= exp(1/100 * t)` and the target:

> K = integral(1/100 * b(t) * exp(-1/100 * t) dt)

Which gives a general solution:

> a(t) = K + C * exp(-1/100 * t)

, where `K` and `C` depend on the value of `b`, resp. the initial value of `a`. If b(t) is constant, then

> **a**(t) = **b** + (**a**(0)-**b**)*exp(-1/100*t)

Remember that exp(0) = 1 and exp(-infinity) = 0

### What does this all mean?

`A` follows an exponential path from its starting point to `B`: initially it travels fast, but is slows down the closer it gets to `B`.

The link I mentioned shows an example of such an exponential curve, for some different starting points, all going to 50:

[image: exponential curve]

Comment: thank you.that's what exactly i want.but i need time to absorb it.

Answer (score 3):

Well you are still using the vector difference between them, you are just moving 1% of the distance toward position B at each step. When the distance is great, the step is larger and the steps get smaller as you approach.

This code has cool advantages. Want it to approach quicker: divide by a smaller number. Want it to approach slower: divide by a larger number.

Additionally, Position B can be a moving object. A moves towards B, B moves. In the next step the vector is recomputed so A moves towards the new B position.

Comment: Yes.i know what it actually does. i would like hear something about mathematical point.

Answer (score 2):

Shades of [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes). After each step, the remaining distance between the two positions is 0.99 times the remaining distance in the previous step, and (0.99)^n goes to zero as n goes to infinity. Long before infinity, the distance will shrink to less than a pixel. Datatypes and round-off errors give a complicating factor since it is conceivable that `diff` might underflow to 0 prior to the two positions being identical (if you are using floats to represent them).

Comment: Good point.It's true that floating point underflow happen to every iteration with larger diff added to "A" position.